# Display line says index was out of range

Tags: vb.net

There is a button that displays an item from an array by searching an input in another array. In this instance, I want to display an item from animalArray.

To do this, a user needs to input a certain name from the nameArray. Binary search, will compare the input and nameArray(middle). But when all that is done, when displaying the array using listbox it crashes and says "index was out of bounds of the array". Even though all items in all arrays has 9 items including 0.

```
binarySearch(nameArray, animalArray, InputBox("Enter Owner name", "Owner name"))
```

How to solve this?

```
Sub binarySearch(ByVal array1, ByVal array2, ByVal item)
    Sort()
    Dim low = 0
    Dim high = 9
    Dim middle As String
    Dim subfindindex = -1
    Do While low <= high And subfindindex = -1
        middle = (low + high) \ 2
        If array1(middle) = item Then
            subfindindex = middle
            Exit Do
        End If
        If middle > item Then
            high = middle - 1
        Else
            low = middle + 1
        End If
    Loop

    ListBox1.Items.Add(array2(subfindindex)) '<--- index was out of bounds of array

End Sub
```

Comment: Which is it—`VBA` or `VB.NET`? You can't have 'em both ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're comparing a number to a name, and attempting to determine which is greater:

```
If middle > item Then
```

Instead, you'll want to compare the number (the value of the `middle` variable) to the *index of* the name in the name array.

That said, you'll get more mileage with this by using lists instead of arrays, and by descriptively naming and strongly typing your parameter variables. Here's the working code:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Animals As New List(Of String)
    Dim Names As New List(Of String)

    Animals.Add("Dog")
    Animals.Add("Cat")
    Animals.Add("Sheep")
    Animals.Add("Goat")
    Animals.Add("Chicken")
    Animals.Add("Fish")
    Animals.Add("Cow")
    Animals.Add("Snake")
    Animals.Add("Rabbit")
    Animals.Add("Squirrel")

    Names.Add("Jim")
    Names.Add("Betty")
    Names.Add("Frank")
    Names.Add("Paul")
    Names.Add("Susan")
    Names.Add("Debbie")
    Names.Add("Bob")
    Names.Add("Tina")
    Names.Add("Fred")
    Names.Add("Bill")

    Me.BinarySearch(Names, Animals, InputBox("Enter Owner name", "Owner name"))
  End Sub

  Sub BinarySearch(Names As List(Of String), Animals As List(Of String), Name As String)
    Dim SubFindIndex As Integer
    Dim Middle As Integer
    Dim High As Integer
    Dim Low As Integer

    SubFindIndex = -1
    High = 9
    Low = 0

    Do While Low <= High And SubFindIndex = -1
      Middle = (Low + High) \ 2

      If Names(Middle) = Name Then
        SubFindIndex = Middle
        Exit Do
      End If

      If Middle > Names.IndexOf(Name) Then
        High = Middle - 1
      Else
        Low = Middle + 1
      End If
    Loop

    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(Animals(SubFindIndex))
  End Sub
End Class
```

But there's a lot simpler way of accomplishing the same goal:

```
Sub BinarySearch2(Names As List(Of String), Animals As List(Of String), Name As String)
  Dim Animal As String
  Dim Index As Integer

  Index = Names.IndexOf(Name)
  Animal = Animals(Index)

  Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(Animal)
End Sub
```

**--EDIT--**

Here's what you should see after entering a name from the list in the `InputBox`:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually after reading yours i found out that i need to use array1(middle) > item to compare, but now it says "index out of range".

Comment: @jazteng ~ Did you try the code samples I provided?

Comment: yes i tried using the middle > array1.indexof(items)

Comment: @jazteng ~ And it still doesn't work for you? (Use the code as-is, without modification. Better yet, use `BinarySearch2()`.)

Comment: The problem still lies in the listbox1.items.add(array2(subfindindex).

Comment: could it be the array itself?

Comment: @jazteng ~ Did you run the code I provided, unmodified?

Comment: i copied and paste i just change the variables of name and animal and item nothing else still lies in display part

Comment: @jazteng ~ Start a new `WinForms` project, create a new form called `Form1`, add a `Button` and a `ListBox` to it, press F7 and paste the code directly into the editor (again, absolutely unmodified — *don't change a thing*). Press F5 to run the application.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work, i just paste everything there is, the problem is still in the display. (I made a new project with a listbox and button

Comment: @jazteng ~ What do you mean, "in the display?"

Comment: The me.listbox1.items.add(...)

Comment: @jazteng ~ This is Visual Studio with `VB.NET` and not `VBA`, correct?

Comment: OK, it's `VB.NET`. No apologies—we'll get this worked out.

Comment: @jazteng ~ You've got a lot of extra complex logic there that you don't need. Did you try adding and calling `BinarySearch2()` instead of `BinarySearch()`?

Comment: Done but there's the problem is the animal = animal (index) [out of range[

Comment: @jazteng ~ Good going. You figured it out.

Comment: Sorry but it did not work I'll try a different search

Comment: @jazteng ~ You must be changing the code somewhere. It works without error as is (see my edit above).

Comment: Ok now it works sorry my mind isnt there. I keep searching another name than the one in the array. Because I kept typing it so ya.

Comment: @jazteng ~ The programmer's poem: "I hate programming. I hate programming. I hate programming. It works! I *love* programming."